# Add a elliptical/hamburger menu inside cytoscape node using Cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

Is it possible to add a menu inside a node of a graph using cytoscape.js library? I am looking to add a hamburger button or elliptical button and when you click on it, it opens a menu and then you have actions on each item inside the menu.

Is it possible right now using cytoscape.js. If yes, can you please show me a demo with code of how it is working? I am currently using Angular.

Here is a stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/cytoscape-call-method-child-zbayfs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: context-menus might be functional for your case. https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-context-menus Otherwise putting HTML inside nodes might be challenging. You might take a look at https://github.com/kaluginserg/cytoscape-node-html-label

Comment: @canbax Thank you, I will give it a shot to context menus